# Range for models.TextField() in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Will there be any range or something like how many characters will be stored in the models.TextField() in Django models? Looks like there is no particular range mentioned in documentation. Will the size just increases as we use the field?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the size just increases as we use the field?

Yes.
It's possible to define a max_length in a TextField(), but according to the docs: ["it is not enforced at the model or database level. Use a CharField for that"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#textfield).

Comment: What if we don't define a max_length for a TextField(). How long will it store in the field.

Comment: max_length in a TextField() will only affect the form according to the docs, so, the only real limit to the size of a TextField() is the database of your Django project. Mysql can store up to 4,294,967,295 characters (4 GB).